# java parent access static variable of child

Tags: java

I have a parent class `Table` that is extended by children.

Parent Class:

```
abstract class Table{

    public static String getFullTable(){
        return child.DBTABLE + '.' + child.DBNAME;
    }

}
```

A Sample Table

```
class User extends Table{
    public static final String DBTABLE = "user";
    public static final String DBNAME = "test";
}
```

When calling `User.getFullTable()` I want to retrieve the value `test.user`.

Can this be done?

Comment: Don't ever have your superclass depend on its subclass(es).

Comment: If you need this behavior defined by data at the child level, make the method abstract and let the child class implement it.

Comment: i was trying to avoid this but looks like i might have to do what you said

Comment: The whole point of abstract methods is to defer implementation to the subclass, why wouldn't you want to do this?

Comment: Please accept Sotirios' comment as the answer to this question. If your super-classes are dependant on the behavior or structure of their subclasses, then something is very very wrong with your architecture and things WILL break/be unmaintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Add abstract methods that request the information from the child class, as such:

```
abstract class Table{

    protected abstract String getDBTable();
    protected abstract String getDBName()

    public String getFullTable(){
        return getDBTable() + '.' + getDBName();
    }

}

class User extends Table{
    public static final String DBTABLE = "user";
    public static final String DBNAME = "test";

    protected String getDBTable() {
        return DBTABLE;
    }

    protected String getDBName() {
        return DBNAME;
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that I changed `getFullTable()` to be non-static. Having a static method in an abstract class that is intended to depend on what subclass it is doesn't actually make any sense.